# ng-Repeat in horizontal

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of a result of a search, I want to have at least 3 items horizontally and then a line break. I tried using the following [css](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/7j92u/2/) but had "broken" the layout. How I can do this?

```
    <div class="list-group">
      <ul ng-repeat="agencia in listaAgencias | filter: pesquisar" class="list-group">
        <li ng-show="pesquisar.length > 0" class="list-group-item" ng-click="selecionarAgencia(agencia)">
          {{agencia.nome}}
        </li>
      </ul>
```

[image]

Comment: Set `inline-block` to the result item and then set a container on the results with a width to achieve your results

Answer (score 2):

how about use this css

```
ul {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 80%;
}

ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7j92u/74/

Comment: You saved my day, thanks for solution. `list-style: none;`